# WPF DataGrid: Disabling selection over multiple columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to keep the user from making cell-selections over multiple columns by hooking into the DataGrid's `SelectedCellsChanged` event.

For some reason, though, my code behaves a little strange.
[image: This is what happens]

And here's my code:

```
private void chartDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in e.AddedCells)
    {
        // If a selected cell is within a different column than the first selected cell, undo the selection (to prevent selections from crossing multiple columns)
        if (cell.Column != e.AddedCells[0].Column)
                    this.chartDataGrid.SelectedCells.Remove(cell);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got rid of this behaviour, but stumbled upon another problem with the new code, which looks like this:

```
private void chartDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in e.AddedCells)
    {
        // If a selected cell is within a different column than the first selected cell, undo the selection (to prevent selections from crossing multiple columns)
        if (cell.Column != this.chartDataGrid.SelectedCell[0].Column)
            this.chartDataGrid.SelectedCells.Remove(cell);
    }
}
```

Now I can't expand my selection to columns on the right (which is good), but I still can to the left.